# Paramiko: Add host_key to known_hosts permanently

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

This code helps me make an ssh connection. I know that `set_missing_host_key_policy` helps when the key is not found in the `known_hosts`. But it is not behaving like the actual `ssh`, because after the first time I run this code, I assumed that that the `host_key` would be added to `known_hosts` and that I need not have the function `set_missing_host_key_policy()` anymore. But, I was wrong `(paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException)`. How can I permanently add the `host_key` to `known_hosts` using `paramiko`? (As a certain part of the backend code is written in 'C' and it needs the `host_key` to be found in `known_hosts`)

Or am I misunderstanding something? I would need some guidance on this...

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=str(host),username =str(user),password=str(pswd))
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the package documentation, compare

```
client.load_system_host_keys(filename=None)

Load host keys from a system (read-only) file.  Host keys read with
this method will not be saved back by `save_host_keys`.
```

with

```
client.load_host_keys(filename)

Load host keys from a local host-key file.  Host keys read with this
method will be checked after keys loaded via `load_system_host_keys`,
but will be saved back by `save_host_keys` (so they can be modified).
The missing host key policy `.AutoAddPolicy` adds keys to this set and
saves them, when connecting to a previously-unknown server.
```

So to make Paramiko store any new host keys, you need to use `load_host_keys`, not `load_system_host_keys`. E.g.

```
client.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/known_hosts'))
```

*But* it's generally a good idea to avoid using `AutoAddPolicy`, since it makes you open to man-in-the-middle attacks. What I ended up doing was to generate a local `known_hosts` in the same folder as the script:

```
ssh -o GlobalKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o UserKnownHostsFile=./known_hosts user@host
```

and then load this file instead:

```
client.load_host_keys(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'known_hosts'))
```

This way I can distribute the `known_hosts` together with my script and run it on different machines without touching the actual known_hosts on those machines.

Comment: If you generate `known_hosts` using `ssh`, it's basically the same as if you generate it using `AutoAddPolicy` (of course, I mean if you generate it yourself and then distribute it with the script). +1

Comment: I find it is a little bit cleaner to use the Path library:
hostkeys = Path.cwd() / 'known_hosts'
client.load_host_keys(hostkeys)

Comment: If one always unconditionally did this, then it would be the same as AutoAddPolicy. But with other usage, it could be quite different. For example, one could have tests which call load_host_keys, to avoid provoking warnings or exceptions during the test even though the code-under-test does not use AutoAddPolicy.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to add one specific key in runtime (without any file):

```py
from paramiko import RSAKey
from paramiko.py3compat import decodebytes

client = SSHClient()

# known host key
know_host_key = "<KEY>"
keyObj = RSAKey(data=decodebytes(know_host_key.encode()))

# add to host keys
client.get_host_keys().add(hostname=HOST, keytype="ssh-rsa", key=keyObj)

# login to ssh hostname
client.connect(hostname=HOST, port=PORT, username=USER)...
```

source: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/2.6.0/tests/test_hostkeys.py#L75-L84

Comment: This is ssh. How do you set the known_hosts when the server only allows basic sftp connections?

Answer (score -6):

##add user remotely ssh using paramiko

```
import paramiko
import os

ssh= paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('192.168.10.49', port=22,username='root', password='abc@123')
def addnewuser():

    uname=input("Type your new Create userName")
    upass=input("Enter Password")



    os.system("useradd -m -p "+upass+" "+uname)

addnewuser()
```

Comment: How does this answer a question about *"Addoing host_key to known_hosts permanently"*?